# restricting the value of the field based on another referenced field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table whose primary key is referenced in several other tables as a foreign key. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `user_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
  )

  CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`customer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
  )

  CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` int NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer`);
  )
```

How can I restrict the value of product.user_id based on the value of the product.customer_id. I want the product.user_id value to be always equal to the value of the customer.user_id where customer.customer_id = product.customer_id

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't want to store `user_id` in the `product` table.  You should always look it up, using the `customer_id` field.

If for some strange reason you do need to include it, then you can define a second key on `customer` and another foreign key relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`customer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
    UNIQUE (customer_id, user_id)  -- redundant, because customer_id is already unique
  );

CREATE TABLE `product` (
   . . .,
   FOREIGN KEY (customer_id, user_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id, user_id)
  );
```

Comment: I fail to see how redundant data contributes to security or to improving management of the system.